# How to delete the documents that fall above a particular timeline in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed a nearly a million documents in my elasticsearch index. But due to a flaw in the code, some of the documents are indexed with timestamp values in the future. 
Now when I check for the last indexed documents, it is showing the documents with future timestamp values. So I need to delete such documents from my index. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to fire a query to fetch document ids with future timestamp values using [scroll/scan](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-request-scroll.html) API and then issue a [bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) request to delete them.

If you are using ES < 2.0, then you can also do it in a single query using [Delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/docs-delete-by-query.html). It is deprecated in v2.0.